# How difficult would it be to change the variables $ prefix into an arbitrary character in php?

Tags: php, binaries

The question is simple.
What if I wanted to prefix variables with © instead of $ in php, just for the sake of fun?
Would it be hard to achieve?
And a multicharacter prefix?

Comment: What about a space as prefix ?

Comment: Even a nonbreaking space would do :P